# Tell if remote computers are online/offline

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I have a bunch of computers(running windows 7) at different locations around the city  and I need to know which of the computers is online in real time. Since none of the computers have a static IP address, i am unable to use the usual mechanisms of pinging the computers.

My initial idea was to create a windows service and install it at each client, then have the respective services ping a central server (I have an amazon EC2 account, running windows OS) which can keep track of when the last ping from each respective computer was received. A website based dashboard would then read the DB from the server and tell if the respective computers are online/offline based on the last recorded ping.

Now all of this seems to be a lot of work for something which must be quite common an issue. Can anyone suggest a out of box solutions or a similar mechanism to achieve my goal of monitoring online/offline status of remote computers which have no static IP address. Thanks

Comment: One convention is to install a service on the client PCs that periodically "phone home" to some server reporting "I'm alive".  You might also be interested in something like [FreeDNS](http://freedns.afraid.org/)

Comment: Depending on your configuration, you could use dynamic DNS. That way, you could ping their DNS names. Do a Google search for [dynamic dns]. You'd need a different DNS name for each site, and you'd have to configure the router to let the traffic through, but it's a possibility.

Comment: I would go your way. Other solutions won't be simpler...

Answer (score 3):

A friend of mine used www.no-ip.org.
What he did was running the program on his computer that connected to no-ip.org and keeping a certain address (for example: my_computer_1.no-ip.org) up to date so it linked to his PC even when the IP has changed. Like that, you can set up a pseudo-static address for all of your PCs and try to connect to those to see whether the PCs are online or not.
I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

PRTG monitor?

http://www.paessler.com/prtg

It's mostly used for servers, but would work great for your scenario.

Comment: You could set up a PRTG core server on your EC2 system and run a remote probe on each of the computers (probes connect to the core server and report their status and the status of their LAN). (Disclaimer: I am the founder of the vendor of PRTG)

Comment: P.S. this is a far simpler and probably more effective solution than dynamic DNS and requires 0 coding.